# Why BaseAdapter getview is mixing my data in rows?

Tags: android, android-view, android-adapter

I am using BaseAdapter to customize my listview

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (view == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.products_item, null);
            }

            FileBean file = (FileBean) ((ExtendedList) (Object) categories.get(groupPosition)).getItem(childPosition);

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.fileCheckBox);
            if(checkBox != null){
                if(mCheckBoxListener != null){
                    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckBoxListener);
                }
                checkBox.setChecked(file.isChecked());
                Log.d("getcview", String.valueOf(file.isChecked() + " " + file.getName() 
                        + " " + groupPosition + " "  + childPosition));
            }

            setProductDetails(file, view);

            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.groupPosition = groupPosition;
            holder.childPosition = childPosition;
            Log.d("exadapter", "Child " + file.getName());

            view.setTag(holder);
            return view;
        }
```

Comment: have you set the getCount and getItem ??

Comment: mixing my data in rows?

Comment: yes getcount and get datitem work normaly

Comment: "mixing" - I mean when it set checked one check box in one row and when i scroll list it stay checked in many rows or remove all check

Comment: Maybe you need to check the logic from where you populate your "categories" object

Comment: when i remove if (view == null) it work normaly

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is related to the fact that your view is recycled when you scroll your list view. You have to reset each time the correct value for your checkbox (checked or not).

You are doing it but your order is wrong and your OnCheckListener is fired each time you reset the checkbox checked/not checked value (you set the listener first, and then you change the checkbox value).

1. Remove the OnCheckListener
2. Set the checkbox value
3. Add your listener again

The correct order:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
checkBox.setChecked(file.isChecked());
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(mCheckBoxListener)
```

Comment: I don't see where when I look at your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Override this two method in your baseadapter class:

```
@Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        if (getCount() != 0)
            return getCount();

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        return position;
    }
```

See if it works.

Comment: getViewTypeCount or getChildeTypeCount?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems,

1 - Move your LayoutInflater out of the getView method, you are creating a lot of garbage there. Instead, create an instance variable to store the LayoutInflater, and create it in your constructor for the adapter. (This has nothing to do with the mixing btw) .

```
private LayoutInflater mInflater; //instance variable

public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
    //some code
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

2 - You are creating your ViewHolder instance on **every** call to getView(). 
Move this code:

```
ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
holder.groupPosition = groupPosition;
holder.childPosition = childPosition;
Log.d("exadapter", "Child " + file.getName());
view.setTag(holder);
```

inside the null check for the converview. You want to only create a new ViewHolder when the converView is null (only on new views).

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
            boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    //First, get the Tag from the converView
    ViewHolder mHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    //Now check if the holder is null, rather than checking if the convertView is null.
    if (mHolder == null) {
        //init the holder code
        view.setTag(mHolder);  //only set the Tag if it's a new view.
    }
```

Also, you are sort of using the ViewHolder pattern the wrong way, you should use the ViewHolder to store the CheckBox for instance, so you don't have to call `findViewById(R.id.fileCheckBox);` on every getView call.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Better adapter optimisation but doesn't fix the OP problem.

Comment: i try this but it not help, i deleted if(view == null) check